# Windows EC2 Instance Key Pair Management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

we have a Windows EC2 instance created. We have a need to remote desktop into the instance occasionally to execute a PowerShell script that updates Microsoft's Power BI Gateway. This is all implemented in a sandbox environment. We're looking at steps/actions to implement in a production environment. From research, I have found that we need to have a different key pair for each user. I think this makes sense. But, the logistics of implementing this is beyond my knowledge. I have some basic questions that perhaps can help steer me in the right direction:

- How do I generate a key pair for each user? Where would these be maintained? How do I assign the key pair by user? Do I need to create a new user in the IAM console?
- Is there a way to rotate the key pairs?
- An instance can only have a single key pair associated with it at a time. Does this mean that after each use, I should detach my key pair and the next user needs to attach their key pair? This all seems very manual.

This is the first I've had to deal with virtual servers and security management of said server. But, it seems that AWS would offer a service that automates this process?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you consider that you "need to have a different key pair for each user"? What is this keypair used for? It is for accessing "Microsoft's Power BI Gateway"? What are you wanting to do with the keypair? For example, is it for logging into the Windows instance, or for calling an external service? More information, please!

Comment: My initial concern is that a user woud rdp into the instance using the password provided from using a key-pair. We have come up with a solution that allows us to create a user is Windows with a default password (that can be changed in Windows once they log in). This would allow us to manage individual users as opposed to using the "admin" user and password.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to automate common admin tasks across your EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

When a Windows Amazon EC2 instance is launched, a random Administrator password is generated.

This password is then encrypted using the keypair selected when the instance is launched. You can access it via "Get Windows Password", and supplying the keypair.

Once you login, you are welcome to change the Administrator password or connect the instance to Active Directory.

You can also create additional Windows logins for your other users.

So, your choice is to either "share" a login for whoever needs to run the script, or give them each their own Windows login and their own password.

I also like @jarmod's idea of using the Systems Manager Run Command to execute a script without logging in!